# SQL--Pairwise condition

Tags: sql

Does SQL have any pairwise conditions in the WHERE clause that aren't using IN?
My use case is I have two tables: (Date, ID) from table ABC and (LaunchDate, ID) from table XYZ. My condition is that ABC.ID is in XYZ.ID and ABC.Date>=XYZ.LaunchDate (for that corresponding ID).  However, if I have (3/5, 1) in ABC and (3/4, 1) in XYZ, a pairwise IN won't work because (3/5, 1) isn't in XYZ?

What I have right now:

```
select date,ID 
from ABC where (date,ID) in (select LaunchDate, ID 
                             from XYZ 
                             where date>=LaunchDate)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really hepl.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `exists`:

```
where exists (select 1
              from xyz
              where xyz.id = abc.id and abc.date >= xyz.lunchdate
             )
```

In general, I recommend `exists` over `in` anyways with subqueries, because `exists` is usually simpler to optimize (although some databases do quite well optimizing `in`).